# Is there a way to type hint two objects being of the same type in Python?

Tags: python, type-hinting

For example, I want to write:

```py
def f(g: Callable[[str], A], h: Callable[[A, A], bool]) -> bool:
    # do something
```

where `A` could be of type `Any`. However writing:

```py
def f(g: Callable[[str], Any], h: Callable[[Any, Any], bool]) -> bool:
    # do something
```

seems misleading since `h` does not explicitly say that its two arguments must be the same type, and that it must be the same type as the result of g.

Comment: Use a generic TypeVar for the types that should be the same?

Comment: Use a type variable, that's what they are foe

Comment: I'll add as answer

Answer (score 0):

We can use `typing.TypeVar`s to type hint this.